# Mail API - MailChimp VS Amazon SES VS mailgun

Tags: reporting, mailchimp, amazon-ses, mailgun

We are looking at integrating with some kind of mail service API but the key thing is we need extensive reporting. I cant get much details on this from the different providers short of contact them so I thought id just ask and find out if anyone knows which service has detailed reporting?

I assume Amazon SES would be the best choice (+ price is good) but confirmation that their service offers really good API reporting would help finalise my decision.

We will be hooking into their API for reporting and displaying the reports on our clients CMS. No, we dont want to redirect the client to any of the provider's login as we want all the clients website data centralised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since asking this question I have landed up using MailChimp's API. At the time of asking I couldnt find info on a MailChimp API with reporting.

Great API and features but quite complex replicating their back-end within your own CMS (especially campaigns).

Answer (score 1):

With Amazon SES you have all the reporting that you want, but you will have to generate it yourself. Clicks/Bounces/Opens - Amazon SES does not provide you with any of these out of the box, not by an API and not by their console.

Mandrill (which is mailchimp's api service) does provide much more extensive repoting built in, but last I checked, you can't access it by API, only in their dashboard.

I have no idea about mailgun

Comment: Mandrill is no longer free.